# My Php telegram robot (php) has error

Tags: php, telegram-bot

> [Mon Apr 24 15:27:18.386224 2017] [:error] [pid 13455:tid 140239221724928] [client 66.102.9.3:51192] PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/parsprog/domains/parsprog.ir/private_html/bot/whoseeprofile/index.php on line 51, referer: Google

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
//connect To DB
$servername = "localhost";
$dbusername = "parsprog_wsmpp";
$dbpassword = "13721372";
$dbname = "parsprog_wsmpp";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
}
//show welcome message From DB
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE subject LIKE 'welcome'") or die($conn->error);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $welcomemsg =  $row['message'];
   echo $welcomemsg;
}
    $userid = '';
    $username = '';
    $fname = '';
    $lname = '';
    $date = '';
//Telegram BOT Connection
$url = "https://api.telegram.org/token";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$keyboard = array(
    'keyboard' => array(
        array('A'),
        array('B'),
        array('C'),
    ),
'resize_keyboard' => true
);
//IF text is: /start
$welcometxt = "hi ".$data->message->from->first_name." dear";
if($data->message->text == '/start'){
    file_get_contents($url.'sendmessage?chat_id='.$data->message->chat->id."&text=".urlencode($welcometxt).".&reply_markup=".json_encode($keyboard));
    $userid = $data->message->chat->id;
    $username = $data->message->from->username;
    $fname = $data->message->from->first_name;
    $lname = $data->message->from->last_name;
    $date = date("y-m-d");
    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO members (id,userid,username,fname,lname,datesignup) VALUES (,$userid,$username,$fname,$lname,$date)");
}
if($data->message->text == 'A'){
    file_get_contents($url."sendmessage?chat_id=".$data->message->chat->id."&text=hi ".$data->message->from->first_name." dear .&reply_markup=".json_encode($keyboard));
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: We need more code and the input..

Comment: What is `$input`? Are you sure that it's what you think it is? Are you absolutely certain?

Comment: Did you put json_decode() to code?

Comment: Please Review again

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment jet so: You wrote a plain text password to in your code and published it! I recommend you to change it immediately!

For your original question: If you want to send a message you need the following `https://api.telegram.org/botYOURBOTTOKEN/sendmessage?chat_id=YOURCHATID&text=YOURMESSAGE` With a short look over your code I saw that there was `$url = "https://api.telegram.org/token";` and later `file_get_contents($url.'sendmessage?chat_id='.$data->message->chat->id."&text=".urlencode($welcometxt).".&reply_markup=".json_encode($keyboard));` which can't send anything. Start there and look how it goes, I can't promise you that this was the only error.

Incidentally, your submitted code only got 49 lines and the error code you provided says line 51, so I guess you didn't submit the right piece or something?